# jquery alert one then two then one then two... and so on

Tags: jquery, random, alert

> ```
> <script>
> function oneortwo(){
> var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
> alert(num);
> }
> </script>
> <button onclick="oneortwo()">click</button>
> ```

Above script is randomizing one and two.
I would like to alert one, then two, then one, then two.. and so on.
If one is alerted, next value will be two and vice-versa.
Basically, I do not want the previous value to be repeated if it has already been alerted.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Set the value of the button on each click, then you can tell what they clicked last and what to change it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
function oneortwo(){
    num = num == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    alert(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var counter = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1); // initially random
function oneortwo(){
    counter = (counter == 2) ? 1 : 2; 
    alert(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the initial 'randomness' this should work.

```
var num;
function oneortwo() {
    if (num == 1) num = 2;
    else if (num == 2) num = 1;
    else num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    alert(num);
}
```